Is it inappropriate for a record to have static members?
I am wondering if it is out of place for a record to have static members, like one for counting the number of instances of the record that have been created.
Below is some sample code (it is just for learning concepts, it does not serve any purpose , but the hopefully the concept of static members in records might in the future...)
namespace RecordsStaticMember;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Rec rec = new("Scott Pilgrim");
        Rec rec2 = new("DarkWing Duck");
        Console.WriteLine(Rec.Count);
    }
}

public record Rec{
    private static int count;

    private string name;

    public string Name{get;set;}

    public static int Count{
        get{
            return count;
            }

        set{
            count = value;
            }
        }

    public Rec(string name){
        Name = name;
        count++;
    }
}

Is there a disadvantages to having static members in a record? Or is it against the "aesthetics" of the language?

What question do you have in your code that needs answering in this way?  I read your count variable as "Here is a count of all of the instances of this record that exist anywhere in my program."  Is that useful information, or is it only useful in the context of a collection, which already has its own way to determine how many items are in the collection?

Questions regarding the ""aesthetics" of the language"  tend to be opnion based.

As to the question "are static members useful in a record?"  Yes, for the same reasons they're useful in a class: factory methods, etc.

While there may be arguments to avoid specific static members in specific implementations of records, I cannot think of anything that would generally speak against it. And the same arguments could be applied to non-record classes, too, I guess.

Sidenote: You may want to read up on "Auto-Implemented Properties".

This has little to do with aesthetics or the usefulness of static properties. The disadvantages depend on what count is meant to be (btw it's not thread-safe, so that's the first problem). What's the real purpose of Count? If you want an autoincementing ID, it's better to have a separate Sequence type that can be used by multiple records. If you want to count all generated instances, a Metric is appropriate.

@RobertHarvey The question for me is about convention, i am kind of new to c# and so I am not aware yet of all conventions and best practices. The code runs but i wanted an informed opinion as to what was not proper...

You'll develop taste for good code when you gain experience.

Records aren't that different from classes. Records just have some members automatically implemented (e.g. the Equals operation) so that they're particularly useful as data containers.
So when you would have a reason to use a static field on an "ordinary" class, the same reason also applies to records. In fact, there's an use case that I use rather often for your piece of code. Let's change it a bit:

public record Rec{
    private static int nextIdentifier;

    public string Name{get;set;}

    public int MyIdentity{get;}

    public Rec(string name){
        Name = name;
        MyIdentity = Interlocked.Increment(ref nextIdentifier);
    }
}

Now we have a field (MyIdentity) that will get a new value for each instance created. Might be helpful particularly if the record is serialized in some way.

I am aware it was in the original from Question, but mind there is a private field name which will never be used.

You're thinking about auto-incrementing IDs. A purpose-build Sequence type would be better than an implied Sequence in each type. As a "count" of instances it would be wrong because it doesn't get decreased when instances become orphans

@PanagiotisKanavos No, the main use of this concept would be to make sure every instance has an unique ID. It does not matter that after a time, the sequence of numbers of the existing instances is no longer be continuous. Also, it works without the memory overhead of a sequence type keeping track of all instances.

@PanagiotisKanavos Maybe it would make more sense if we rebrand it to "Count of Instances created since start of the application" ?

Or as "Object ID that is available at all times", not just when debugging.

@Fildor Clarified names to make it more clear.

3 different people, 3 different assumptions. That's why this count isn't a good idea. BTW there's no overhead to a single Sequence or Counter instance that wraps a count and gets used when creating multiple record instances

Anyway, the actual question as I read it "are records supposed to never have static members" should be answered with "no, there are legit use cases - generally speaking" - can we all agree on that?
